# Incomplete total envelopes through this endpoint /search_folders/completed?start_position=0

Tags: docusignapi

I try to get my complete envelopes through this endpoint Auth//search_folders/completed?start_position=0 but this just back me 349 totalrows, so i checked it the platform and i have more than 349 complete envelopes, why the API just gave me that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Folders/Folders/search) say that the default `from_date` value is the last 30 days.

The DocuSign web tool has a default of last 6 months. (See the filter popup.)

So to get the same results as the web tool, set `from_date` to the current date - 6 months.

Comment: Thanks for you help, it work, i'll share my new endpoint  Auth/search_folders/completed?start_position=0&from_date=2018-01-01 and that back to me 4770 totalrows, thanks again.

Comment: Hi @LuisRico -- glad it worked. Thank you for the check!